# Snapping doesn't work properly with custom axis

Tags: snapping, axis

Good day (again). I'm trying to snap the vertex by custom axis, but it snaps really weirdly for some reason. I attached some screenshots. Thanks.[image]

Comment: We cannot even see if you're using snap during transform or not, and what kind of "Snap To" you choose ... Moving a vertex along its edge is pretty simple, and Snap mode works in any case.

Comment: I pressed G, then Y, and in the up-left corner I can see that it's moving along the local custom axis. I selected snap to vertex, and chose the vertex which is inside the orange circle.